# Защита от DDOS атак в golang

Tags: golang, ddos

Подскажите, как защитить веб сервер на golang от DDOS атак?

Comment: Язык программирования не зависит методов защиты от DDOS.

Comment: Если vps без внешнего балансировщика, то поднимай go-приложение за nginx и смотри как защитить nginx от DDoS в гугл. Но если овчинка того стоит, то тебе просто забьют канал и ничего не поможет. Поможет конечно, но меры эти - не панацея. А иногда достаточно сменить хостера. Некоторые хостеры своих клиентов DDoS-ят, чтобы потом впарить анти-DDoS защиту за бабки. Вообще спонтанный (просто залётный) DDoS не проблема, обычно он рассчитан на всякие WordPress, Joomla и не сильно напрягает.

Answer (score 2):

Запрос пользователя -> внешний ip антиддос сервера -> система очистки трафика -> их nginx -> очищенный трафик поступает на наш сервер -> nginx -> apache -> и обратно пользователю по этой же цепочке.

[16 РЕЦЕПТОВ ЗАЩИТЫ ОТ DDOS-АТАК СВОИМИ СИЛАМИ](https://xakep.ru/2012/12/29/16-antiddos-recipes/)

Comment: Самое главное не спалить злоумышленнику реальный IP адрес вебсервера.

Comment: Я куплю vps (так что ставить могу всё что захочу) и домен, Но ip ж можно у любого домена узнать, написав просто ping. Не очень Вас понял. Я этой темой не занимался- вот только сейчас решил. Я ещё думал такой вариант- может определить ip пользователя и если,скажем, идёт ну очень много запросов с этого ip-то вырубить на часик-два? (конечно я и других людей с этого адреса вырублю...но что ж поделаешь)

Comment: если своими силами то я скинул ссылку на статью, а выше показана робота платных серверов защиты от DDOS, как работает система.

Answer (score 0):

В своё время мы перешли на  https://www.cloudflare.com/ Он защищает от атак и прячет реальный IP серверa.

Comment: ip можно все равно узнать. если брать бесплатную версию, то от нормальной ddos атаки он не поможет